# Convert image to base64 with the angular library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

i have a problem to convert an image to base64 with the library base64 of angularjs.

see my function :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = conf.storeUrl + '/' +$scope.fRoot.name + $scope.getFileWay() + value.name;
var base64Img = base64.encode(img);
```

the url of the image is good and the image has been created but the base64Img is empty... i don't understand why.... Some one have a idea ?

thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
/**
 * Convert image 
 * to a base64 data uri
 * @param  {String}   url         
 * @param  {Function} callback    
 * @param  {String}   [outputFormat=image/png]           
 */
function convertImageToDataURI(url, callback, outputFormat) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

**Usage**

```
convertImageToDataURI('ImageLink', function(base64Decoded){
    // Base64DataURI
});
```

**Supported input formats**

```
image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/bmp, image/tiff, image/x-icon, image/svg+xml, image/webp, image/xxx
Supported output formats

image/png,image/jpeg,image/webp (chrome)
```

**Demo:**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)

**Test: toDataUrl mime type**

http://kangax.github.io/jstests/toDataUrl_mime_type_test/

**Browser Support (so far I know)**

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas
- IE10 (IE10 just works with same origin images)

**Images from the local file system**

If you want to convert images from the users file system you need to take a different approach. Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/xztfbx1m/)).

Comment: i test this solution but the event onload don't work when i set the src attribut....

Comment: But i will try with fileReader and back

Comment: Have you see the fiddle?

Comment: yes i have but i almost  solved my problem :) i inpired of the convertImageToDataURI function :) but now it's my base64 it's not good :/

Comment: Perfect ;) have you got another stuck?